# Creating Groups of points based on proximity in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clustering, grouping, spatial-cluster

I have a dataset with around 900 points and I want to cluster them into groups of 44 based on proximity.

Is this possible in QGIS?

I have tried to use the convex hull tool with no success.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **ClusterPoint** plugin. After installing the plugin, a tool named **doCluster** is added to Processing Toolbox.

*Cluster Points* adds a new field `Cluster_ID`to the attribute table as output. (In the image, points are styled categorically by `Cluster_ID`)

[image]

Comment: Originally, that was also my answer :). But as @Sapecedman rightly pointed out, OP wants to create clusters with 44 points (not 44 clusters), which seems to be more difficult task than to handle with this algorithm.

Comment: Could you do the total number of points divided by the number of points wanted in a cluster? (900/44 = 20.45...) obviously you will end up with some discrepancy if not an integer.